# How to save a string to a database from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I'm trying to save a string to the database and output it from the view. Just starting to learn RoR, so a bit confused here...

Here's what I did:

- generate model test id :string value :string

followed by

- rake db:migrate

then I opened the rails console from ./script/rails console

I'm trying to type this here:

test.create!(:value => "Hello World")

but it returns "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments" :(
How can I do this correctly?
Also, how can I store this to a variable and output it in the view?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Test.create!(:value => "Hello World")`. `create` is a class method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model should start with an uppercase letter;

```
Test.create!(:value => 'a string')
```

Comment: You're likely running into the fact that the name `Test` is already taken by `Test::Unit`, which is a part of Ruby.

Comment: exactly right - test is probably a reserved word.  Also, what Kenrick was trying to point out is that you use the Propercase of the word for creating records on that model, Test not test.

Comment: Can you use a model name other than Test?  You may be conflicting with some gem or class in your codebase?  Try creating model like `Book`.

Comment: Hah - works now! Thanks so much, looks like I just ran into some teething problems :)

Comment: Also, how can I define a method in my controller so that this value is attached to a variable?

Comment: @var = TableName.find(value) ?